# Series solution for a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series

I have the differential equation $(1-x^2)y'' -2xy' +\lambda y = 0$. If I solve it with a power series of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x+1)^n $ centered at $x=-1$ I got a recurrence relation. Should I get the same recurence if I solve my differential equation with a power series of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ centered at $x=0$? Should it give the same coefficients $a_j$?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Comment: In general, the coefficients in the Taylor series of a function centred at different points will be different unless the function has symmetry (expanding $\sin$ at 0 and $2\pi$ yields the same result).  Thus one would expect a priori that the recurrence relation is different.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Can we have a series solution at any point we like to have ( where the function is analytic ). Will both the solutions​ be right.